# ActiveX Control - MFC Locale

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, activex, msvcrt, setlocale

I have an MFC application developed with Visual Studio 2008 where I use Adobe ActiveX control (I have Adobe Reader X installed). I try to set the zooming rectangle using the setViewRect function and it works perfectly.

Now the problem appears when in my Windows Regional Settings, the decimal symbol is set to comma instead of dot (such as in the German Regional Settings). The parameters of the zooming rectangle seem to be interpreted incorrectly.

I used ProcessMonitor and discovered that when Adobe ActiveX Control is created and its DLL is loaded in my process, it calls setlocale, and hence the application is using the current Windows Regional Settings instead of the default "C" locale. Therefore, the application interprets the numbers in a wrong way.

I tried to reset the locale to "C" right after loading Adobe and this workaround fixed the problem.

Now the problem happened again when I migrated my application to Visual Studio 2010. Apparently Adobe DLL ("c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroPDF.dll") is developed using Visual Studio 2008. So when it sets the locale, it is done in MSVCR90.dll. When I reset the locale, I did so using the same DLL.

Now as my application is in VS2010, calling setlocale is done in MSVCR100.dll, so it does not affect the locale already set in MSVCR90.dll.

Is there a way to set the locale of the COM object that I am hosting inside my application?

Thank you so much in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but you could try loading MSVCR90.dll with `LoadLibrary` (since the DLL is already loaded, it'll just give you a HANDLE to it, it won't load it twice), then finding the pointer to its setlocale function with `GetProcAddress`. Then you will be able to call the setlocale function for this DLL. It's an ugly hack, but it might work.

Comment: Thank you satuon for your reply :)
I tried to do so, but unfortunately LoadLibrary(_T("MSVCR90.dll")) returns a NULL handle. It works only when I LoadLibrary with the full path to MSVCR90.dll (C:\\Windows\\winsxs\\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\\msvcr90.dll) which is not feasible to do.

Comment: Yes it did :) Thank you for the tip :)
I just cannot use the full path in my application.

Comment: See [EnumProcessModulesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682633(v=vs.85).aspx) and [GetModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx). I found them just by Googling "enum process dlls" and "get module filename". If you don't search for a way, you won't find it. You shouldn't give up so easily.